# Show user that program still. Running

Tags: java

I wrote  a Java program that reads a file, process the numbers and then output result to to the user. The processing could take a while  so I would like to display some sort of progress bar or just simply thinking glass (anything reallly)  that indicate to the user that the program is actually processing something.

Any recommendation for quick Solution for it?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you print a dot to stdout after every x records processed...

Comment: Quickest might be to use a [`ProgressMonitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying a Progress Bar while a calculation is occuring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579291/displaying-a-progress-bar-while-a-calculation-is-occuring)

Comment: is this a swing application?

Comment: When you say stdout, don't of mean system.out? If that's the case then it does not show any pop up window?

Answer (score 1):

Display a busy cursor:

```
try {
  component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
  // process
} finally {
 component.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
}
```

Comment: this is definately the quickest :)

Comment: Thank you but what would be the full code (i.e component)? Right  now here is no gui or anything.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...

**Command line progressbar**

http://nakkaya.com/2009/11/08/command-line-progress-bar/

```
public static void printProgBar(int percent){
    StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder("[");

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        if( i < (percent/2)){
            bar.append("=");
        }else if( i == (percent/2)){
            bar.append(">");
        }else{
            bar.append(" ");
        }
    }

    bar.append("]   " + percent + "%     ");
    System.out.print("\r" + bar.toString());
}
```

Comment: Although this would answer the question, you should add some of the content from that link to your answer. Just in case the link gets unaccesible or someother thing.